# When ever I build by react-native project I am facing issue Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'React.RCTRuntimeExecutorFromBridge

Tags: ios, react-native, build, react-native-image-picker

[image]When ever I build by react-native project I am facing this issue

`Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'React.RCTRuntimeExecutorFromBridge`

even If I clean my project still this issue occurs

My project is running fine but I don't know why this issue keep coming even I haven't install any package.